# page events in master page and content page

Tags: vb.net, events, master-pages, content-pages

The thing is i have a Master page and a Content Page. I have a LoadComplete in Content Page and a PreRender in Master Page. The problem is one of my htmlcontrols on content page i change on the LoadComplete event server side of the content page. 
I also have some code for disabling controls on the Master Page PreRender event.
For some reason all controls on the aspx side go through the Master Page prerender except the ones that i change on the LoadComplete side.
How can i make sure the entire content page loads and then the Master Page PreRender event is called, making all the controls go through that event.

Answer (score 0):

You need to carefully review this document on the asp.net page lifecycle.

It will explain exactly what order page events occur in.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx